# finding the kernel of a polynomial transformation $P \to P$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

• Let $P$ denote the vector space of polynomials and $l : P → P$ be defined via
$p(x) \mapsto x^2p(x) + xp'(x)$

How do I find the kernel of this transformation? I am having a hard time setting up a system that I can set equal to 0. Conceptually, I understand that if I can set up a matrix I will be able to show linear independence or dependence and from that determine the kernel.

Comment: You don't need to use matrices. The kernel consists of all polynomials $p$ that are mapped to $0$ under $l$. What happens if you set $l(p) = 0$? Can you characterize such $p$? As a hint, you should get a differential equation to solve.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using differential equations? this is for linear algebra @ViktorVaughn

Comment: Even in a linear algebra class, your instructor might want you to use some knowledge of differential equations.  Here, however, you don't really need any, since it's hard to see how $x^2p(x)$ and $xp'(x)$ can cancel terms and add up to $0$.

Comment: this still seems unclear to me. I have no knowledge of differential equations. I do understand that it needs to add to 0. How would I do that though? @AllenBell

Comment: This comes down to just degrees of polynomial. Gave a walk through to almost the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1x+a_0$, then $p'(x)=na_nx^{n-1}+\dots +a_1$.

Hence the condition is $(a_nx^{n+2}+a_{n-1}x^{n+1}+\dots+a_0x^2)+(na_nx^n+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x)=0\implies a_nx^{n+2}+a_{n-1}x^{n+1}+(a_{n-2}+na_n)x^n+\dots +(a_0+2a_2)x^2+a_1x=0$.

But when a polynomial equals zero, all of the coefficients are zero (reason? ).

So, $\forall i,2\le i\le n,\, a_{i-2}+ia_i=0$.  And $a_n=a_{n-1}=a_1=0$.

Thus the coefficients are all zero.

So the kernel is trivial.

Comment: I know that since this only has the trivial solution it would be injective, but would this transformation be surjective as well? @ACME

Comment: Good question.   It's not clear at first sight whether any polynomial can be written in this form.  Since the space is infinite dimensional,  it is entirely possible that the answer is no.   Let me think on it.  Actually,  I just noticed that there's no constant term.  Thus the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $p(x)=0$ gets us $$x^2p(x)+xp'(x)=0$$
Factor out the x to get
$$x(xp(x)+p'(x))=0$$
since we want this to be the 0 polynomial, it has to be 0 for all $x$, not just $x=0$,  so we need
$$xp(x)+p'(x)=0$$
Solving this outside the context of polynomials would require differential equations.  However, since we know $p(x)$ is a polynomial,  we can avoid that difficulty.   Subtracting one term to the other side gets us
$$xp(x)=-p'(x)$$
This says the polynomial on the left is the same as the polynomial on the right, so they have the same degree.  If $p(x)=0$ (undefined degree),  the equation is true.

So assume $p(x)\neq 0$,  so it has a well defined degree.   What's the degree of the LHS and the RHS here? Can you finish?

Comment: If $p(x) \neq 0$, we have $p'(x)/p(x) = -x $, so $ln(|p(x)|) = -x^2/2 + c$, but now I'm stuck.  How do we finish the proof? I think maybe use asymptotic growth rates of $ln$ and a polynomial? But $p(x)$ can be any polynomial and there's a $+c$ at the right side.

Comment: you reach the trivial solution, yes? @Alan

Comment: @DavidLui you're doing too much work.  leave it at $p'(x)=-xp(x)$, then note the degree of the RHS s greater than the degree of the LHS unless $p(x)=0$.

Comment: @belushi1 Yes,  by the consideraiton of the degrees above